# SSMS "Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server"

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am using SSMS (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) to connect to an Azure SQL database. I have selected "SQL Server authentication" and entered the admin login and password. For some reason it still tries to use Windows authentication regardless of the authentication being set as "SQL Server authentication" and reports

> Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

I have tried this on another computer and it works fine (also a different network). This new computer for some reason does not work despite the same server name login and password.

I can connect to the database via Visual Studio SQL explorer on the same PC no problem proving its not a firewall issue.

Why is it not using SQL Authentication?

Secondly how can I simply enter an SQL connection string instead of using the GUI to connect? I have a working SQL connection string which works in C# code but am completely stumped how to use the GUI.

**Update**

I have tried entering part (or all) of the database connection string into the "Additional Connection Parameters" window which then gives a different error:

> A network-related instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 No such host is known). Error 11001

**Update 2**
edit: After 24 hours the problem has magically resolved itself, PC was not rebooted, nothing was changed.

Comment: Which SSMS version do you use? Can you try uninstall it and install again? Can you show us some screenshots? How about AAD login?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version from the website this morning v18.6. What is AAD login? What screenshots do you want to see?

Comment: When you give SQL login, it is not supposed to use windows login. can you please elaborate on that more ?

Comment: @rolls Try Azure Active Directory authentication to connect to Azure SQL database. The screenshot about login screen, we can the server type,server name, authentication and so on. And the screenshot of the error message details.

Comment: @VenkataramanR that is what I don't understand either. I clearly select SQL server authentication but the error message is saying that windows login is not supported despite it never being selected at any stage of the process. It seems like a bug.

Comment: Ok I just tried again today and everything connects fine now no error message. Absolutely no changes have been made, not even a reboot.

Comment: If I purposely incorrectly select windows authentication I can reproduce the problem. But SQL Authentication works as expected. Definitely something buggy happening here as I tried many many times with different logins, it isn't even possible to enter a login unless you select SQL authentication so I have no idea why it didn't work yesterday other than something to do with the install process which required something to timeout/crash in the background.

Comment: Hi @rolls,Congratulations! We're glad to hear that the error is resolved. The update can be post as the answer then other people may know it. Azure SQL database doesn't support windows authentication. Thanks for the sharing, I just help you post it. You can think about accept it as answer. This may be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: It's not really an answer though. There is an obvious bug/issue which is unresolved.

Answer (score 5):

SSMS 2019 has a bug, once you manually select windows authentication, it creates the problem to connect with azure. So just restart ssms(no need to restart pc) by closing from task manager and carefully fill-up the fields. It will work

Comment: This answer solved my problem. Seems like a bug in the dialogue screen or the dropdown. Anyhow I hope Microsoft will solve it in a next release.

Comment: Hey! Works for me!

Comment: The current latest version of SQL Server Management Studio (19.3.4.0) is still affected by this bug.

Comment: sometimes you just to restart the app only. In my case, I closed the app and re-run SSMS. Mine SSMS 19.3

Answer (score 1):

We are glad that the error is resolved in the end:

"After 24 hours the problem has magically resolved itself, PC was not rebooted, nothing was changed."

Thank for sharing the details for us:

"If I purposely incorrectly select windows authentication I can reproduce the problem. But SQL Authentication works as expected. Definitely something buggy happening here as I tried many many times with different logins, it isn't even possible to enter a login unless you select SQL authentication so I have no idea why it didn't work yesterday other than something to do with the install process which required something to timeout/crash in the background"

If others can provide more analysis, we're still very grateful.

Comment: I had the exact same issue just now, fresh SSMS install with a fresh Azure SQL Database. It kept complaining about 'Windows Authentication', while I was using 'SQL Server authentication'. Finally a reboot fixed the issue, magically.
Feels like a bug in SSMS or Azure sql db that mixes up Windows & Sql login.

Comment: 2023 and this bug remains, rebooting the PC has fixed the issue. OpenAI, Chat GPT, ..., but here we are rebooting our computer to fix an issue