I am trying to connect to Azure SQL Server from SSMS

Cannot connect to devsqlserveravdrutuja.database.windows.net.
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server.
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40607)

I tried copying the correct server name as well as the password

Please provide what you have tried and what did you get in proper way, edit the question according to it?

I found a similar thread in the StackOverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002224/ssms-windows-logins-are-not-supported-in-this-version-of-sql-server

The error is clear Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server.. You'll have to use a SQL User.


Title: Connect to Server
Cannot connect to dbserver.database.windows.net.
Additional Information:
Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40607)

According to this MS document, Azure SQL Database doesn't support Windows authentication. It supports only SQL Server authentication and Microsoft Enterprise ID authentication. That may be the reason you are getting the above error. To connect to an Azure SQL Database from SSMS, copy the server name and server admin from the connection string page of the SQL Database as shown below:

Then, select SQL Server authentication in SSMS and enter your username, password and connect it as shown below:

The Azure SQL Database will connect successfully to SSMS as shown below:

